# API to select a file in Eclipse using an external application

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to **select/open a specific file in a specific project in Eclipse** from an external application.

**Does Eclipse provide an API for such tasks?**

I'd like to link a visual representation of an application's structure to like to eclipse. If I **click on a symbol** in the external application, I'd like to **open the related file** in Eclipse.

Comment: You want an external application to tell Eclipse to open a file within the Eclipse IDE? Or are you developing your own RCP application? The whole Eclipse environment is essentially an API.

Comment: I want to open a file within the Eclipse IDE. Alternatively, if you count provide pointers for an RCP tutorial, this would be helpful too.

Comment: If these two don't help let me know. http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html#editor_ieditorinput
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822261/open-editor-at-start-in-an-eclipsercp-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a simple Eclipse Plugin that was listening for an Event to open the file. I do not believe Eclispe provides such support since you can have multiple Eclipse's executing at the same time and there isn't an easy way to identify them except through the opened workspace.

I suggest you create a simple Eclipse Plugin that listens on a open socket or pipe. It can wait for a command from your external application. When it receives this command it can then scan for the appropriate project using the Eclipse PDE API's then open the file.